# How to find out if email adresses exist?

Tags: python, email, email-validation

I've got a list of emails that got corrupted by some robots. On my webpage I have a box "sign in to our newsletter" that got abused with fake adresses and now I can't make up the good adresses from the fake adresses.

I would like to write a small script that check the existence of all the adresses one by one preferably without sending an email. The list isn't that long (about 300 email).

Can I do this without breaking anti-spam rules? I know that I should send an email with a link for people to verify their email but I don't really want to do this as the people with real adresses have already opted in my newsletter and they are going to wonder why I ask them to do it again.

I would ideally do this with python as this is my scripting language of choice.

Any solution to this?

Comment: what are you using to send newsletters? Didn't your latest newsletter send mailer-daemons on the bad emails?

Comment: I use mailchimp but with all the bad adresses they took me for a spammer and deleted my list. So I only know that I have bad adresses but don't know which one!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure how to do it yourself, however, there are services for this. I use [Kickbox](http://kickbox.io). I typically use nodejs for the server, but they have a python library [Kickbox-python](https://github.com/kickboxio/kickbox-python/tree/master). You can do 100 verifications a day for free, or pay for more. I use it to verify emails when users initially sign up.

EDIT: The [kickbox](http://kickbox.io) pricing model has changed. Now you get 100 initial verifications free, and pay for any additional verifications after that threshold. Refer to the site for the current pricing plans.